# service broker in EC2 environment

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

Maybe somebody know if service broker can be used in EC2 environment. For example, I have two instances. One is running SQL Standard and the other is running SQL Express. Can service broker be used in this set up. Note: I know that Amazon RDS does not support service broker.

Comment: Have you tried it? From what I know, SQL on EC2 is just normal SQL (perhaps with some weird networking), so it *should* work. So try it out and see what happens!

Comment: Thanks. You are right. I just need to prove the concept in case we decide to go this route. I was hoping that I will not have to actually configure the set up on EC2. It seems there is no documentation confirming that the SQL Server running on EC2 instance is the same as running on-premise.